# Iteration keeps going even when I try to break it

Tags: python

Im trying to display the time in the .txt file which is in words=[5], the loop works but never stops iterating, I even tried calling for a class when i==10 but after it goes trough that method it keeps iterating again(infinitely)

```
def NextHour(self):
    
    with open("flightdata.txt","r") as file:
        lines=file.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            l=9
            if l==10:
                self.Compare(time)
                break
             
            elif l!=10:
                words = line.strip().split(',')
                time=words[5]
                print(words[5])
                times=[]
                times.append(time)
                
                print(l)
                l=l+1
            else:
                self.Compare(time)
                break
```

was expecting l to stop the loop as when it gets incremented it would go and break itself

Comment: [Rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) would be very useful in this case. Go and explain each line of code inside the for loop. What happens with `l` as firrst line in every iteration, regardless of what you did in the previous iteration of the loop? Hint: the `elif` part has no `break`

Comment: in the first iteration (line) in the for loop, you set l=9. You then enter the elif block and increment it to 10. In the second iteration of the for loop, you start by setting l back to 9 again. This causes you to re-enter the elif block, and the same thing will keep happening indefinitely because there's no break condition in the elif block

Comment: In your loop, the variable *l* will only ever have one of two values - 9 & 10. You have 2 *break* instructions. Neither of them will ever be executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You overwrite the `l` variable with each iteration. Move it's initialization `l = 9` before the loop. The same applies to the `times` variable.

```
def NextHour(self):
    with open("flightdata.txt", "r") as file:
        lines=file.readlines()
        l=9  # I took this number from your example
        times=[]
        for line in lines:
            if l==10:
                self.Compare(time)
                break
            
            # No need for `else` after the break
            words = line.strip().split(',')
            time=words[5]
            print(words[5])
            times.append(time)
            
            print(l)
            l=l+1  # alse `l+=1` would work
```

Also, you should check out the [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function, which helps keep up with the count of iterations.

```
with open("flightdata.txt", "r") as file:
    lines=file.readlines()
    times=[]
    # Again, I took the number 9 from your example.
    for l, line in enumerate(lines, start=9):
        if l==10:
            self.Compare(time)
            break
        
        # No need for `else` after the break
        words = line.strip().split(',')
        time=words[5]
        print(words[5])
        times.append(time)
        
        print(l)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help but even with your (second paragraph)code for some reason the whole method gets executed everytime it hits the index 10 as if it restarts, and the Compare() method never gets called?

Comment: @CodeCrusher9000 if that did not help, I'll need more inputs from you. Can you provide me with the code for the whole class, please? And example content of flightdata.txt, please?

Comment: Thanks, no it worked I was just calling the method in a loop thanks for the help